# STS Dashboard defaulting to old with error

Tags: eclipse, spring, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have a new installation of STS 3.6.0.  I have the installed JRE set to `jdk1.7.0_65`.

However, I can only view the old-style Dashboard, and the icon seems to have an indication of an error over it, although I can't seem to find a way to see what the error actually is.

[image]

This isn't a terribly critical issue, but it sure is annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a new installation of STS 3.6.0. I have the installed JRE set to jdk1.7.0_65.

That is the problem the new dashboard in STS 3.6.0 requires JDK 8, because that is what JavaFX support in Eclipse 4.4 requires. If you don't have JDK 8 there will be an error opening it and it will fallback to the old dash.

Also, the red circle the icon isn't an error but a marker that there are unread items in the 'news' section of the dash. Maybe that's not obvious.

I think that if you are using the old dahsboard the unfortunate side effect is that this 'unread items' marker can't be cleared because you can't read the news items in the new dahsboard, so it will always be there.